# Android if else statement not working inside onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, if-statement, onclick

I have a list view that displays values (names) I get from my website, then loads the url link corresponding to that name in a web view using onItemClickListener, that works fine! but when I add a if statement it doesn't read it, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onPeriodicosListClick = new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        cambio="";
        pUrl="";
        noteId = arrayOfWebData.get(position);
        cambio  = noteId.Medio.toString();
        PeriodicosListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
        pUrl = noteId.website.toString();
        wvp.loadUrl(pUrl);

        if ( cambio == "Periodico"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    cambio,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if ( cambio == "Tv"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    cambio,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
};
```

the (cambio  = noteId.Medio.toString();) can only be Periodico, Radio, Tv (as I have set the value of it to be any of those 3 word only) so all I want is a tost to be display telling what it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be

```
if(cambio == "Periodico")
```

but

```
if(cambio.equals("Periodico"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but if cambio is a String object, the if statement should be

```
if(cambio.equals("Periodico") {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The == operator checks to see if two objects refer to the same space in memory (not the content of the string). Strings are objects which means the == operator does not do a content check but a reference check. Use the instance [compareTo(String anotherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method to compare the contents of strings i.e:

```
if (cambio.compareTo("Periodico") == 0) { /* match */ }
if (cambio.compareTo("Tv") == 0){ /* match */ }
```

There is also an [compareToIgnoreCase(String string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) and [equalsIgnoreCase(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) variant if case does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a switch statement instead of if? Also what do you get if you output cambio to the logCat using

```
Log.d(TAG, "cambio: " + cambio);
```

One last thing. What are you using to connect the List to your activity? A simpleAdapter, baseAdapter, ..?

Comment: No, I haven't use the switch statement, because I son't know how to implement it in this case. I'm using an ArrayAdapter